# How to fire property changed notifications from C# to COM using IPropertyNotifySink?

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I am going crazy on this problem for the past couple of weeks. I have a C# Com object that needs to send property change notifications to a C++ Com object. An equivalent in VB would be using code that looks as follows
PropertyChanged "propertyName".

In C++ the equivalent to use the CFirePropNotifyEvent class from ATL.

The C++ COM and VB COM objects do not implement a specialized events interface, so the equivalent are give above.. The C++ COM object that needs to sink the event is based around IPropertyNotifySink, afaik.

What is the equivalent in C#?
 i have tried:

1. INotifyPropertyChanged from System.ComponentModel
2. I implemented IObjectWithSite and tried to cast the site object received in setSite to IPropertyNotifySink.

   1. I cannot find an equivalent for CFirePropNotifyEvent in C++/ATL which is what the C++ code uses..

Please help..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is some automatic gateway between .NET's INotifyPropertyChanged and COM's INotifyPropertySink.

If you want a .NET object to provide COM events, you need to provide an implementation of [IConnectionPointContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683857%28VS.85%29.aspx) in these .NET objects.

`IConnectionPointContainer` already exists in .NET in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComType`s namespace.

Comment: hmm.. good point.. i did have a (unsuccessful) go at implementing that.. is there any help available (generics impl/sample ??)

Comment: It's hard to find. If you really want to go this route, I suggest to dive in Reflector and look around the interface, also around the AxHost class which is the CLR wrapper for AciveX objects. It's not documented but Reflector can tell a lot about it. Otherwise you can advise your own "event-like" mechanism using delegate, callbacks, etc. If it's possible in your context, it's much simpler.